# Following Sharetribe install instructions and getting error "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;"

Tags: mysql, ruby, macos, terminal

I'm a complete nubie to Ruby but have managed to get this far following these instructions:
https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe

But a straight copy/paste of this code into terminal results in errors. Any ideas?

```
c = Community.create(:name => "your_chosen_name_here", :domain => "your_chosen_subdomain_here")

tt = c.transaction_types.create(:type => "Sell",
 :price_field => 1,
 :price_quantity_placeholder => nil);

tt_trans = TransactionTypeTranslation.create(:transaction_type_id => tt.id,
 :locale => "en",
 :name => "Sell",
 :action_button_label => "Buy");
ca = c.categories.create;
ca_trans = CategoryTranslation.create(:category_id => ca.id,
 :locale => "en",
  :name => "Items");
CategoryTransactionType.create(:category_id => ca.id, :transaction_type_id => tt.id)
```

Errors are:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'c = Community.create(:name => "marketfarm", :domain => "marketfarm")
c = Communi' at line 1

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tt_trans = TransactionTypeTranslation.create(:transaction_type_id => tt.id,
 :lo' at line 1

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ca = c.categories.create' at line 1
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying out Sharetribe!

First of all, we have updated the installation instructions. New installation instructions do not require this step.

In you case I guess there's somekind of copy/paste error there. Maybe you could try first copy/paste the command to a text editor (i.e. Notepad) and remove the line breaks and make the commands single line. I have notice that sometimes console doesn't understand multiline pasted commands.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using any other database like sqlite or postgresql than Mysql.
Sharetribe only supports with Mysql database.

Thanks